How does the Ricci tensor describe the changing separation of two airplanes flying from the equator? Conceptually understanding the Ricci tensor
I'm trying to understand the concept of the Ricci tensor and its physical implications using a concrete example involving two airplanes. Suppose two airplanes start at the equator, separated by a small longitudinal distance, and fly north along geodesics (longitudinal lines on the Earth's surface). As they fly north, the distance between them decreases due to the curvature of the Earth.

How can we use the Ricci tensor to describe the changing separation between these two airplanes?
How does this relate to the geodesic deviation equation?
How can we directly calculate the changing area between their geodesics using the Ricci tensor?

Here's what I have understood so far:

The Ricci tensor $ R_{ij} $ is derived from the Riemann curvature tensor and provides information about the volume change in a small region of space.
For the Earth's surface (modeled as a sphere), the Ricci tensor components are related to the curvature of the sphere. Specifically, $ R_{\theta\theta} = R_{\phi\phi} = \frac{1}{r^2} $, where $ r $ is the Earth's radius.

Starting with the geodesic deviation equation:
$$ \frac{D^2 \eta^i}{d\tau^2} + R^i_{jkl} u^j \eta^k u^l = 0 $$
In our example, where the separation vector $\eta$ points in the longitudinal direction ($\phi$), and the airplanes are moving in the latitudinal direction ($\theta$):
$$ \frac{d^2 (\Delta \phi)}{d\theta^2} + R^\phi_{\theta\phi\theta} (\Delta \phi) = 0 $$
Since $ R_{\theta\theta} = \frac{1}{r^2} $, this simplifies to:
$$ \frac{d^2 (\Delta \phi)}{d\theta^2} + \frac{1}{r^2} (\Delta \phi) = 0 $$
Solving this differential equation, we get:
$$ \Delta \phi (\theta) = \Delta \phi_0 \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{r}\right) $$
Thus, the area between the geodesics at latitude $\theta$ can be described as:
$$ \Delta A (\theta) = r^2 \Delta \theta \Delta \phi_0 \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{r}\right) $$
I would appreciate it if someone could confirm this understanding and provide further insights into how the Ricci tensor components specifically describe this changing area and separation in the context of general relativity and differential geometry.
